# TCP stack tuning

Tags: networking, rhel, tcp

I have a couple Oracle Linux 6 systems acting as [rsyslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd) remote receivers. I'm pretty much certain the TCP stack is overloaded, and I've been trying to tune it. But, I'm at the end of my Google searches, and I don't know what to try next. I've been through these sites already

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/
- http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/files/linux-kernel/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

along with a bunch of uselessness. Here's the tuning I've tried so far:

```
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 5000
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
```

And, I'll still get unanswered packets coming in. (The source is a test application just sending zero-length packets.)

```
2017-12-12 15:25:41.053937 IP SENDER.34394 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 1418245921, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117377413 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:25:42.053458 IP SENDER.34394 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 1418245921, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117378413 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:25:44.053578 IP SENDER.34394 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 1418245921, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117380413 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:25:48.053582 IP SENDER.34394 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 1418245921, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117384413 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:25:56.053803 IP SENDER.34394 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 1418245921, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117392413 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:12.055312 IP SENDER.34394 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 4104732283, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117408413 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

And, if my receiver does answer the incoming requests, it seems to ignore the test FIN flags for several tries before it RSTs the connection:

```
2017-12-12 15:25:55.632684 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 3551538126, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117391991 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:25:56.632380 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 3551538126, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117392991 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:25:58.631714 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 3551538126, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117394991 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:02.632298 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 3551538126, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117398991 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:10.632477 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [S], seq 3551538126, win 18352, options [mss 9176,sackOK,TS val 1117406991 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:10.632517 IP RECEIVER.514 > SENDER.56008: Flags [S.], seq 1010914189, ack 3551538127, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1002368883 ecr 1117406991,nop,wscale 8], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:10.632983 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [.], ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117406991 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:10.664428 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117407023 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:10.865080 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117407224 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:11.267436 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117407626 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:11.772951 IP RECEIVER.514 > SENDER.56008: Flags [S.], seq 1010914189, ack 3551538127, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1002370024 ecr 1117407626,nop,wscale 8], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:11.773690 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [.], ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117408132 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:12.071025 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117408430 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:13.679547 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117410038 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:13.772915 IP RECEIVER.514 > SENDER.56008: Flags [S.], seq 1010914189, ack 3551538127, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1002372024 ecr 1117410038,nop,wscale 8], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:13.773784 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [.], ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117410132 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:16.895194 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117413254 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:23.327789 IP SENDER.56008 > RECEIVER.514: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 144, options [nop,nop,TS val 1117419686 ecr 1002368883], length 0
2017-12-12 15:26:23.327833 IP RECEIVER.514 > SENDER.56008: Flags [R], seq 1010914190, win 0, length 0
```

So, I think I'm still backlogged, in that my TCP stack isn't getting to all the incoming packets as fast as it should. But, I don't want to start messing with further settings without some better documentation references and a better understand of how the TCP stack settings interact with each other.

For bonus points, does anyone have a utility better than `netstat -i` to track the TCP stack in real time?

*UPDATES:*

- These hosts are not load-balanced, but I do have keepalived running a Virtual IP address, so I get a bit of failover if the primary system dies.
- These hosts are OL6 VMs on top of VMware.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help with the primary question itself, but as far as the secondary question, a good network monitoring and statistics gathering tool worth checking out is `iptraf-ng`.

Comment: Tuning is a black art. Also have a look at `tc` (traffic control) if priorizing packets can help.

Comment: First tuning is hardware, and I think rsyslogd is the slower part (or you have crap network hardware).

Comment: Is your box behind a load balancer? Check this http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html. How many new connection requests per second is your server receiving? How long a single connection takes to be served? Are you sure that your hardware and application can handle the current load? Take a look at this page if you didn't please http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html